# Socket epoll: Will EPOLL_CTL_MOD reset the edge trigger?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll, epollet

Start by adding a socket to an epoll set for edge triggered reading:

```
epoll_event ev = {};
ev.data.fd = sock;
ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;   // edge triggered reading
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sock, &ev);
```

Now wait for data:

```
result = epoll_wait(efd, events, sizeEvents, timeoutMilliseconds);
```

Hypothetically, let's say there was 20+ bytes of data available.  But the subsequent code wants to parse messages off the stream in 10 byte chunks:

```
result = recv(sock, buffer, 10, 0);
```

So at this point, you're probably saying, "if he invokes `epoll_wait`, his code may hang or timeout even with the remaining 10 bytes in the socket stream that have yet to be read."  And you would be correct.

But instead of going back to epoll_wait, my code actually switches epoll flags so it can function for sending a response back on that same socket.

```
ev.data.fd = sock;
ev.events = EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, sock, &ev);
```

Notice that EPOLLIN is no longer set.  Then the code does the standard loop of `send` and `epoll_wait` until the full response is sent.

When the message response has been set, the code goes back to reading in edge triggered mode:

```
 ev.data.fd = sock;
 ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
 epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, sock, &ev);
```

Followed by a wait:

```
 result = epoll_wait(efd, events, sizeEvents, timeoutMilliseconds);
```

Now assuming no additional data has arrived on `sock` since the last read off the socket, does the above `epoll_wait` hang (or timeout) since the edge level hasn't changed?  Or does the fact that EPOLLIN was toggled off and on again allow the edge state to be reset such that the above `epoll_wait` call would return immediately to indicate data available on the socket?

Comment: The whole point of using EPOLLET is that you don't need to use EPOLL_CTL_MOD at all.

Comment: @pindumb why? I'd say the exact opposite is true since in ET mode you have to write as much as you can even if you haven't received the needed request from the client to do so. That's why you need to first read request then change to `EPOLLOUT` and write the responce

Answer (score 0):

Toggling the monitored event will still cause `epoll_wait()` to hang. `epoll_wait()` in ET mode reacts to a callback function that is triggered when change is made to a file descriptor in terms of the monitored events. You'd still need to wait for some new data to arrive on that `fd` in order to receive `epoll_wait()` notification.